# Remove all markup from user registration field

Tags: hooks, theming

I have been searching in vain for days trying to find the right hook or theme override to basically change a few fields I have defined in a custom registration form.

The default markup generated by Drupal is too verbose and the designer has requested that I not change the CSS -- I need to bend the markup to meet the CSS not the CSS to play nice with Drupal.

I have tried hook_field_widget_form_alter and have managed to wrap the existing markup in *div*'s but I need to remove the default:

```
function tweakform_field_widget_form_alter(&$element, &$form_state, $context) {
  //$element['#prefix'] = '<dir style="background-color: red">';
  //$element['#suffix'] = '</div>';

}
```

Can someone please show me how this is done? I don't want to re-write the entire form.tpl.php as I only need to override a few fields markup -- then again it may be handy to override the whole thing. These fields are dynamic and controlled by designer and more may be added later or possibly removed.

Alex

Answer (score 0):

```
function tweakform_field_widget_form_alter(&$element, &$form_state, $context) {    
  $element['#theme_wrappers'] = '';    
  $element['#prefix'] => '<div class="red">'; 
  $element['#suffix'] => '</div>';
}
```

Comment: OK I have almost achieved my goal...

I am still getting some DIV's added between <form>

xxx-add-more-wrapper

What method contains this extra markup generation??? 

Alex

Comment: form.module adds the extra elements... you can override these in your theme by adding `yourtheme_formfield()` for each element you want to alter, i.e. `yourtheme_form_element()`, `yourtheme_fieldset()`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to change markup, do it in your theme template.php using `THEME_form_element()` just take the function from [theme_form_element](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/theme_form_element/7) and modify it for your theme.  There are also theme hooks for the form and fieldsets.

Comment: I just figured this out, but I am still getting DIV's for each form element without input, labels' etc...I am guessing this is what theme_form and theme_fieldset would allow me to override???

Comment: Yes they would allow you to strip tags too.  There is also a separate one for textareas.

Comment: No textarea, just textfields and a select for now...